# How to generate a vector that orthogonal to other vectors?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a matrix A which is

```
A=[1 0 0 1 0; 
   0 1 1 0 0; 
   0 0 1 1 0; 
   1 1 1 0 0]
```

And a given vector `v=[ 0 0 1 1 0]` which has two elements one. I have to change the position of element one such that the new vector `v` is orthogonal to all the rows in the matrix A.
How can I do it in Matlab?

To verify the correct answer, just check `gfrank([A;v_new])` is `5` (i.e `v_new=[0 1 0 0 1]`).

Note that: Two vectors `u`and `v` whose dot product is `u.v=0` (i.e., the vectors are perpendicular) are said to be orthogonal.

Comment: `v_new` is not orthogonal to the rows of `A`. Do you mean `v_new=[0 0 0 0 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [AVK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6282716/avk) also mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825150/how-to-generate-a-vector-that-orthogonal-to-other-vectors#comment66941872_39825150),  `v_new = [0 1 0 0 1]` is not orthogonal to *all* rows of `A`.

**Explanation:-**

```
A=[1 0 0 1 0; 
   0 1 1 0 0; 
   0 0 1 1 0; 
   1 1 1 0 0]
```

For `A(1,:).*v = 0` to `A(4,:).*v = 0`,

```
0 x x 0 x        % elements of v so that it's orthagonal to the 1st row of A
x 0 0 x x        % -------------------------------------------- 2nd row of A
x x 0 0 x        % -------------------------------------------- 3rd row of A
0 0 0 x x        % -------------------------------------------- 4th row of A
```

where `0` represents the terms which have to be `0` and `x` represents the terms which can be either `0` or `1`.

If you look as a whole, *first 4 columns* of `v` have to be *zero* so that the output is orthagonal to all rows of `A`. *The 5th column* can *either be zero or 1*.

So, 
`v_new` can either be: `v_new = [0 0 0 0 1]` or `v_new = [0 0 0 0 0]`

From above explanation, you can also see that `[0 1 0 0 1]` is not orthagonal to *2nd* and *4th row* of `A`

---

**Solution:-**

To find `v_new`, you can use [**`null`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function as: `v_new = null(A).'` 

 which gives: `v_new = [0 0 0 0 1]` for which `gfrank([A;v_new])` also gives `5`.

Comment: Thank you. I was wrong for `v_new`. The `null` function is a good one. If I want to find the linear independent vector, instead of orthogonal vector. Do you know any function support it?

Comment: @user8430 A new question should be asked separately as a new question! Also consider searching the web before doing that. And if this answer solves your problem then [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) , that's the proper way of saying thanks

Comment: And I check the `null` function. If I am working in GF(2), (means binary matrix), then your method `null(A).'` does not give a binary solution

Comment: @user8430 Are you sure that a binary solution exists? Also you didn't mention that you need only binary solutions

Comment: To add one last thing, if you need a binary solution, ***zero vector*** is always the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you see the orthogonality between two vectors in N dimension.

```
N=100;
B1 = ones(1,N);
B2 = -1*ones(1,N/2); 
B2 = [ones(1,N/2) B2];
B2 = transpose(B2);
B3 = dot(B1,B2);
```

The above code generates two vectors in N dimension. To check for orthogonality just transpose one of the vectors and multiply with the other one. You should get zero if they are Orthogonal.

The example I used makes sure that I get zero indeed.